# How to get data value and set a new data value using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have PHP while loop which showing this value:

```
echo "<a href='$video_url' data-vid='$video_id' class='$active'>$video_title</a>";
```

And I have a HTML iframe:

```
<iframe height="380" id="yframe" data-video-id="" width="800" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxHmoLvjpLs" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen style="margin-top: 30px; float: right; margin-right: 10px; "></iframe>
```

**How its works:**

When I click on the each `a`link it's just getting the `href` value and set it to `iframe` `src` value.

Well, Now you see that I have `data-vid` value in `a` link.

**I want, On first page load the first `data-vid` value should be set to `iframe` `data-video-id` value.**

and then when I click on any `a` link then corresponding `data-vid` value should set to `iframe` `data-video-id` value.

But somehow it's not working.

**here is my JS code:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  var current_vid = $('.vertical-menu a').data("vid");
    $('#yframe').data('video-id', current_vid);

    $(".vertical-menu a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#yframe").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
        $('#yframe').data('video-id', $(this).data("vid"));
        $('.vertical-menu a').removeClass('active');

        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
            $this.addClass('active');
        }
    })
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#next-btn").click(function(){
        $(".vertical-menu a.active").next().trigger("click");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you are using jquery to achieve this. Similar can be done using plain old javascript as well.

Why should set with `attr` not with data is because `attr` in jquery is used to update/set attribute values of DOM elements. Which is a function which takes two parameters (attribute name and value).

Here's how you achieve the same using javascript

```
var yFrame = document.getElementById("yframe");
yframe.getAttribute("data-video-id"); // Returns the value of the attr
yframe.setAttribute("data-video-id","your data value") // Sets the value of attr
```

Answer (score 0):

OH, I found the problem I should set the value using `attr` not `data`. But why?

Here is the code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  var current_vid = $('.vertical-menu a').data("vid");
    $('#yframe').attr('data-video-id', current_vid);

    $(".vertical-menu a").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#yframe").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
      $('#yframe').attr('data-video-id', $(this).data("vid"));
      $('.vertical-menu a').removeClass('active');

      var $this = $(this);
      if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
          $this.addClass('active');
      }
    })
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#next-btn").click(function(){
        $(".vertical-menu a.active").next().trigger("click");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**.data()** will store arbitrary data associated with the specified element and/or return the value that was set.
 .**attr()** will get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched element.

have a look at this [article](https://coderwall.com/p/t_cgwq/when-is-better-to-use-data-or-attr)